# Application was crashed in ipad Air

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad-2, ipad-3

i did one application and submitted to appstore.But application was rejected due to crash problem.But i run on my ipad it's working properly.I send a mail to review team.And they give me reply as "Your application was running successfully in all ipads except ipad Air.Application was crashed in iPad Air".So how to stop the crashing in iPad Air.
And the crash reports are shown like this

```
 Process:         lsd [2500]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/libexec/lsd
Identifier:      lsd
Version:         40
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [145]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-04-04 10:34:28.890 +0530
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.4 (12E55)
Report Version:  10

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000000000001fd

VM Regions Near 0x1fd:
--> __PAGEZERO             0000000000000000-0000000000001000 [    4K] ---/--- SM=NUL  /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/libexec/lsd
    __TEXT                 0000000000001000-0000000000002000 [    4K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/libexec/lsd

Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: release
iPhone Simulator 463.9.4, iPhone OS 6.0 (iPad Retina/10A403)


Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0073509b objc_msgSend + 15
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0098841c CFRelease + 108
2   MobileCoreServices              0x003f3fbb _LSServer_CopyVendorIdentifier + 1335
3   MobileCoreServices              0x0040d912 _LSPluginServer_GetVendorIdentifierForAppIdentifier + 311
4   MobileCoreServices              0x004120bb _XGetVendorIdentifierForAppIdentifier + 238
5   MobileCoreServices              0x0041224d LSPlugin_server + 119
6   MobileCoreServices              0x0041e6e8 serverCallback + 154
7   CoreFoundation                  0x00981c93 __CFMachPortPerform + 131
8   CoreFoundation                  0x00981bf5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
9   CoreFoundation                  0x00981962 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 146
10  CoreFoundation                  0x009b2bb6 __CFRunLoopRun + 2118
11  CoreFoundation                  0x009b1f44 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
12  CoreFoundation                  0x009bdf91 CFRunLoopRun + 129
13  MobileCoreServices              0x0041e638 _LSServerMain + 360
14  lsd                             0x00001aa6 0x1000 + 2726
15  lsd                             0x00001a41 0x1000 + 2625

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x014d19ca kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x01102c2b _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 863
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x011028cc _dispatch_mgr_thread + 61

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0xbfffe5ac  ebx: 0x009883be  ecx: 0x0073c2c4  edx: 0x000001f5
  edi: 0xbfffe5ac  esi: 0x000001f5  ebp: 0xbfffe448  esp: 0xbfffe3e8
   ss: 0x00000023  efl: 0x00010286  eip: 0x0073509b   cs: 0x0000001b
   ds: 0x00000023   es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x0000000f
  cr2: 0x000001fd
Logical CPU: 0

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -     0x1ffb +lsd (40) <C84BC72A-C659-312E-9C08-5F1CAB7FC201> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/libexec/lsd
    0x5000 -   0x292ffb +Foundation (992) <33D58583-D8E9-3E20-9CC1-13C63C9EC28C> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
  0x3e3000 -   0x466ffb +MobileCoreServices (40) <D9ACED0B-062E-390A-822B-F3AF04C26D9F> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
  0x4a1000 -   0x4a4ff7 +MobileInstallation (251) <85DC2B13-85EC-31DB-9771-54E80E911562> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
  0x4aa000 -   0x4c6ffd +libSystem.dylib (65.4) <7095EDF3-1274-3A6D-AB48-C941EC0BD00F> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.dylib
  0x4da000 -   0x691ff1 +libicucore.A.dylib (491.19) <11DCDD9E-2709-3568-A02E-327BE5163C4B> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
  0x71e000 -   0x829f2f +libobjc.A.dylib (532.1.1) <97D87A00-8F28-30CC-B4C0-6E36A69ACDAA> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
  0x842000 -   0x93eff7 +libxml2.2.dylib (22.3) <8C34E1FD-F90B-3158-9A97-D5DC923D52DC> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
  0x96c000 -   0x97bff7 +libz.1.dylib (44) <795F02AA-F065-3D5D-9D06-2A4E4DBC625C> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
  0x980000 -   0xb26ffb +CoreFoundation (793) <6B4B4B13-691B-3CFF-93AB-3AFD3097A9E4> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
  0xc3c000 -   0xdacff3 +CFNetwork (609) <47FBDF79-04B5-38F5-842F-0A63AAB06EAC> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
  0xe53000 -   0xe9effb +SystemConfiguration (499) <1272155C-A362-3F63-A2C2-45350BDAA2B8> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
  0xec0000 -   0xf09ff3 +Security (1326.6) <2CD7C6B1-7699-3801-9028-4DA115290391> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
  0xf2f000 -   0xf34ffe +IOKit (65.4) <9E3253CE-A35B-3BAA-9492-B47110EDE377> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/IOKit
  0xf3e000 -   0xf5dffb +libCRFSuite.dylib (32) <D608B97C-51A7-3299-A5F2-77EE57A02750> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
  0xf67000 -   0xf68ffb +liblangid.dylib (114) <E02691B6-2660-327A-85D9-65079160FF3E> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
  0xf6c000 -   0xf7dfff +GenerationalStorage (130) <FBB045C2-877A-32E0-BA98-CA9AE1B8934B> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
  0xf85000 -   0xfe9ff3 +libstdc++.6.dylib (56) <5F8C495C-35F3-3D7B-AC32-27778B7DECE5> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
 0x1047000 -  0x105affb +libbsm.0.dylib (28) <2503C190-0D01-3D5B-B85E-D01BCA738FBC> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
 0x1062000 -  0x107bfff +SpringBoardServices (2127.8) <64D6B728-7FE7-3051-AFC3-AFA34A2A10F3> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
 0x108e000 -  0x10afff7 +libc++abi.dylib (24.1) <FCBF2B99-631B-396B-870A-38411C972445> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
 0x10d9000 -  0x10d9ffc +libSystem.override.dylib (65.4) <42812ECC-E4E0-3114-A1AA-B179BB4A464C> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libSystem.override.dylib
 0x10de000 -  0x10e2ffb +libcache_sim.dylib (59) <BB7DBAB8-045E-35F3-9635-2AE93040A434> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libcache_sim.dylib
 0x10e7000 -  0x10f1ffb +libcommonCrypto_sim.dylib (60032.1) <1973A2E3-0218-3B23-9C68-8E8D84205AFB> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto_sim.dylib
 0x10fc000 -  0x1114fff +libdispatch.dylib (244.33) <D3AAC264-D870-3488-891A-75B5EF49218F> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
 0x1127000 -  0x1130fff +libnotify_sim.dylib (103.10) <517E3E3A-98C5-3A88-B54D-E6CD8A57D2DA> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libnotify_sim.dylib
 0x1137000 -  0x11a9fe7 +libsystem_sim_c.dylib (849.29) <093F885E-F90D-3E33-AAAF-4D3425A9539C> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libsystem_sim_c.dylib
 0x11ca000 -  0x11cbffb +libsystem_sim_blocks.dylib (60) <E0816229-3EA6-37AD-B22F-70BC70351B6D> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libsystem_sim_blocks.dylib
 0x11cf000 -  0x11d7fff +libsystem_sim_dnssd.dylib (397.33) <D6A8EA9B-A43F-3A20-AD5A-00E5D65768B0> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libsystem_sim_dnssd.dylib
 0x11dd000 -  0x11f0ffb +libsystem_sim_info.dylib (421.3) <FF264FBC-B24E-36C8-BCC7-4D75E5BC2C90> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libsystem_sim_info.dylib
 0x11fb000 -  0x122aff3 +libsystem_sim_m.dylib (3029.2) <D6EEB53F-EA1D-3FFE-B0D5-0C42696E8979> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libsystem_sim_m.dylib
 0x1231000 -  0x1245ffb +libsystem_sim_network.dylib (130.7) <8E5B53B9-BB8F-36DC-ADA2-8C474365F855> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libsystem_sim_network.dylib
 0x1252000 -  0x1273ff7 +libxpc.dylib (173.35) <64B1F71B-74F0-38A0-83B2-5555EBC5F344> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
 0x1286000 -  0x128dffb +libcopyfile_sim.dylib (90.2) <5B4E4523-645A-33C0-BFF8-A90D501CA8C5> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libcopyfile_sim.dylib
 0x1292000 -  0x1294ff7 +libdyld_sim.dylib (212.3) <C1F660E0-A06C-3A40-9F5B-ED6DAD1FAFDC> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libdyld_sim.dylib
 0x1299000 -  0x129affb +libremovefile_sim.dylib (24.2) <E5BACEA1-B6C6-336C-8472-9F1CFDAFAF14> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libremovefile_sim.dylib
 0x129f000 -  0x129ffff +libSystem.host.dylib (169.3) <81C58EAB-0E76-3EAB-BDFD-C5A6FE95536F> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libSystem.host.dylib
 0x12a6000 -  0x12f6fff +libcorecrypto_sim.dylib (121) <1F8AADB6-0A37-30DC-9B88-7FCAE9643A4F> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto_sim.dylib
 0x1303000 -  0x1307ffe  libcache.dylib (57) <834FDCA7-FE3B-33CC-A12A-E11E202477EC> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
 0x130c000 -  0x1317fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib (60027) <8EE30FA5-AA8D-3FA6-AB0F-05DA8B0425D9> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
 0x1322000 -  0x1325ff7  libcompiler_rt.dylib (30) <CE5DBDB4-0124-3E2B-9105-989DF98DD108> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
 0x132c000 -  0x1334fff  libcopyfile.dylib (89) <4963541B-0254-371B-B29A-B6806888949B> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
 0x133a000 -  0x133bfff  libdnsinfo.dylib (453.19) <3B523729-84A8-3D0B-B58C-3FC185060E67> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
 0x1340000 -  0x1342fff  libdyld.dylib (210.2.3) <05D6FF2A-F09B-309D-95F7-7AF10259C707> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
 0x1348000 -  0x1348fff  libkeymgr.dylib (25) <D5E93F7F-9315-3AD6-92C7-941F7B54C490> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
 0x134c000 -  0x1353fff  liblaunch.dylib (442.26.2) <310C99F8-0811-314D-9BB9-D0ED6DFA024B> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
 0x135b000 -  0x135fff7  libmacho.dylib (829) <5280A013-4F74-3F74-BE0C-7F612C49F1DC> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
 0x1364000 -  0x1365fff  libquarantine.dylib (52.1) <094A1501-373E-3397-B632-8F7C5AC8EFD5> /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
 0x136a000 -  0x136bfff  libremovefile.dylib (23.2) <9813B2DB-2374-3AA2-99B6-AA2E9897B249> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
 0x1371000 -  0x1371fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib (59) <3A743C5D-CFA5-37D8-80A8-B6795A9DB04F> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
 0x1375000 -  0x1432feb  libsystem_c.dylib (825.26) <6E35A83F-1A5B-3AF9-8C6D-D7B57B25FB63> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
 0x146e000 -  0x1475fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib (379.38.1) <4F164CA8-4A4F-3B27-B88A-0926E2FEB7D4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
 0x147b000 -  0x14a7ff7  libsystem_info.dylib (406.17) <AA5611DB-A944-3072-B6BE-ACAB08689547> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
 0x14bc000 -  0x14d6ffc  libsystem_kernel.dylib (2050.24.15) <9E58DCC0-D5FF-37E1-AA7F-F2206719E138> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
 0x14e7000 -  0x1514ffe  libsystem_m.dylib (3022.6) <9975D9C3-3B71-38E3-AA21-C5C5F9D9C431> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
 0x151e000 -  0x152cff3  libsystem_network.dylib (77.10) <7FBF5A15-97BA-3721-943E-E77F0C40DBE1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
 0x1538000 -  0x1542fff  libsystem_notify.dylib (98.5) <7EEE9475-18F8-3099-B0ED-23A3E528ABE0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
 0x154b000 -  0x154cfff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (220.3) <C532F6A6-7E85-38F3-8660-EC1066DF67BE> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
 0x1551000 -  0x1552ffd  libunc.dylib (25) <58599CBF-E262-3CEA-AFE1-35560E0177DC> /usr/lib/system/libunc.dylib
 0x1558000 -  0x155fffb  libunwind.dylib (35.1) <E1E8D8B3-3C78-3AB1-B398-C180DC6DCF05> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
 0x1566000 -  0x15b2fff  libcorecrypto.dylib (106.2) <20EBADBA-D6D6-36F0-AE80-168E9AF13DB6> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
 0x15bf000 -  0x15e2fff +BackBoardServices (2127.8) <FD1EE1DF-543E-3319-981D-CF8359485DF2> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
 0x1601000 -  0x1612ff7 +GraphicsServices (504) <B2DDE38F-AA35-30AB-A0B4-B9282DA105A1> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
 0x1623000 -  0x162cfff +XPCObjects (39) <D4B1170E-442D-35BC-A3B3-E7EAEE0A7A8F> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XPCObjects.framework/XPCObjects
 0x1636000 -  0x1645ff7 +libMobileGestalt.dylib (154) <1524F86E-1175-310F-AB3C-370E96CBC16E> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
 0x1652000 -  0x1822fff  com.apple.CoreGraphics (1.600.0 - 400.17) <8C2744FF-6DB5-344A-BBDB-4F8358150087> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
 0x187b000 -  0x18e3ff7 +IOKit.host (755.24.1) <70DE925B-51E8-3C65-8928-FB49FD823D94> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/umbrella/IOKit.host
 0x190e000 -  0x191affe  libkxld.dylib (2050.24.15) <BEC097B0-9D9A-3484-99DB-0F537E71963E> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
 0x191f000 -  0x19e0ff3 +libsqlite3.dylib (142) <279B5524-D0A4-3A85-94F1-0A27DEC83B1D> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
 0x19f1000 -  0x19f5ff3 +MobileSystemServices (1) <F5F1E086-F334-3700-A427-E5C0B8F9A789> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSystemServices.framework/MobileSystemServices
 0x19fb000 -  0x1a33ffb +Bom (189) <43D5F33D-0E1F-32C6-AA13-04DA48A641D2> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
 0x1a42000 -  0x1a4efff +libbz2.1.0.dylib (30) <E1B2BAFE-50A4-3E92-89DE-AEC39AC82CB9> /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x8fe19000 - 0x8fe4be57  dyld (210.2.3) <23516BE4-29BE-350C-91C9-F36E7999F0F1> /usr/lib/dyld

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 1023
    thread_create: 1
    thread_set_state: 565

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=24.8M resident=23.6M(95%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=1212K(5%)
Writable regions: Total=29.9M written=1300K(4%) resident=2776K(9%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=27.2M(91%)

REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
CoreServices                        352K
MALLOC                             20.2M
MALLOC guard page                    32K
Mach message                          8K
Stack                              64.1M
VM_ALLOCATE                          16K
__DATA                             1444K
__LINKEDIT                         6048K
__PAGEZERO                            4K
__TEXT                             18.9M
__UNICODE                           544K
mapped file                       211.5M
shared memory                        12K
===========                      =======
TOTAL                             323.0M
```

So can anybody please explain the problem.

Comment: Test your app on an iPad air

Comment: But i don't have iPad Air.

Comment: If you have a crash log (or a more detailed problem description) then please post that as we cannot help without more information. Otherwise, test in the simulator AND borrow an iPad Air to debug on.

Comment: Did you test in 64-bit iPad simulator? iPad Air is 64-bit.

Comment: Also have you tested the 64-bit iphone simulator? If you have Xcode 6, it's device specific.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question your build crashes on iPad Air and running on all other iPad. As we know iPad Air is a 64 bit device, it might possible that you haven't set the Valid Architecture for 64bit. So, you have to check it in your Build Settings -> Architecture -> Valid Architecture (arm64, armv7, armv7s).

Might this will solve your problem.

Comment: Answering when you are not certain is fine, but this seems like pure guesswork, especially as we know the iPad Air can run 32-bit code just as well.

Comment: @trojanfoe I appreciate your comments, yes answer is purely a guesswork, Please post the correct answer here.